# Every normal operator is a continuous function of a Hermitian operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, normal-operator

For normal operator $N$, prove that there is a hermitian operator $A$ and continuous function $f$ such that $N=f(A)$

I don't know how to start, just I know For normal operator $N$ there is a unique spectral measure $E$ such that $N=\int\lambda\,dE(\lambda)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1972-031-01/S0002-9939-1972-0288617-1/S0002-9939-1972-0288617-1.pdf